# Translate C program into IA32 assembly (very quick)

Tags: c, translation, x86

Just have one little thing I got stuck on while translating this C code into assembly. This is the line of code I am stuck on.

```
if (input == '\n')
```

My assembly code thus far(for this line) is

```
movl input, %eax    #%eax = input
cmpl ___, %eax
```

How do I compare input to '\n'? Do I just compare it outright or do I move it into the memory first? Thanks.

Comment: `cc program.c -S && cat program.s` or `cc program.c && objdump -dr a.out`

Comment: What do mean by "very quick"?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
cmp 0x0D,%eax
```

0x0D is the ascii code for carriage return, or you can try 0x0A for line feed.

Comment: @Serge Ballesta Sorry, my bad. 0x0D is carriage return and 0x0A is line feed. Sorry again. I got them mixed up in my mind.

Answer (score 0):

Compare it directly, `cmp` allows for immediate values.

Comment: So it would just be:
    cmpl '\n', %eax?

Comment: That depends from the exact assembler, but usually it should work. If you are working with GNU `as, that's the correct syntax.